# C++ vector<thread*> push_back(): can't figure out incantation to create unnamed thread variables

Tags: multithreading, c++11, templates

Creating a named thread is working well for me:

```
void inserter( int iTimes ) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < iTimes; i++ )
      DoOne();
}

int main( int nArg, const char* apszArg[] ) {
  std::thread t1( inserter, 100 );
      :
      :
```

But I can't figure out how to do it when creating the threads without a name.  This produces an error that it cannot resolve the constructor.  I'm also wondering whether, once that is working, whether the vector's type will be the right type or whether instead of `thread*` I need to specify template arguments and if so how to do so for 1) the function and 2) the parameter list.

```
using namespace std;
vector<thread*> apthread;

for ( int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++ )
    apthread.push_back( new thread( inserter, i ) );
```

Comment: You are missing `std::`. You don't need to have pointers here, you can `emplace_back` into a `std::vector<std::thread>`

Comment: Please report the exact error message you get a minimum example to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't due to the vector of threads.

Instead, the problem is that the thread function is called `inserter()`, which is also a symbol defined by C++ std libraries.

The vector version, in addition to adding the vector, added `using namespace std;` which prevented the compiler (g++ 7.2.1) from resolving intent.

Changing the function name to practically anything else (not defined by the standard libraries) enables compilation.  Likewise, removing the `using namespace std;` and instead explicitly prepending all library symbols with `std::` works.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing explicitly missing in your example code to make it compile is `std::`: https://godbolt.org/z/3gX_h2

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void DoOne(){}

void DoMany( int iTimes ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < iTimes; i++ )
        DoOne();
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::thread*> apthread;

    const auto nThreads=10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++ )
        apthread.push_back( new std::thread( DoMany, i ) ); 

    // join all the threads
    for(auto& t: apthread){
        t->join();
    }

}
```

However, you should never use plain `new`, and there is no need to use dynamic allocation for `std::thread` anyway: it is already a handle, and you can just `push_back` the new thread object into the vector:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void DoOne(){}

void DoMany( int iTimes ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < iTimes; i++ )
        DoOne();
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::thread> apthread;

    const auto nThreads=10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++ )
        apthread.push_back(std::thread( DoMany, i ) );    

    // join all the threads
    for(auto& t: apthread){
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anthony Williams, many thanks.  My actual problem lay elsewhere (I modified the program description to show it, and answered the question).   I'd still like to understand though: "you should never use plain new"?  Could you expand on that?  And, how do we know thread is a handle?  Is it spec'd to be or does experience simply tell you that in practice it always is?

Comment: @SwissFrank If you use plain `new` then you need to manually call `delete` to destroy the object, which is error prone. If you need dynamically allocated objects, use `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` to construct the object, and then `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to hold the pointer, and ensure it is correctly cleaned up.

Comment: @SwissFrank We know `std::thread` is a handle because (a) a thread is an abstract concept for a sequence of instructions run on the CPU, so we can only hold the OS data structures for it, and (b) it is specified to be nothrow-move-constructible and nothrow-move-assignable, so fundamentally it must be a handle, or at most a collection of handles to the OS data structures. Finally, in practice it is usually a thin wrapper around the `pthread_t` or `HANDLE` returned from the OS.